# Format Y axis tick mark numbers

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using the annotated timeline visualization and I am wondering if
it is possible to format the numbers that are on the side of the Y
axis ( on the Y-axis 'tick marks').

What I need explicitly is a way for these numbers to be truncated to
whole integers, and not display the decimal parts, so they do not take
as much space.

I've gone through the API documentation and there doesn't seem to be a way to do this. Am I wrong?

Thank you,